# PrettyPhoto Linked in button

Tags: jquery, linkedin-api, prettyphoto

I am using Jquery PrettyPhoto plugin. (http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)

And I added facebook like , twitter share, linked in share ve google plus buttons.

All buttons works ok but in a three photo sequence linked in button is seen only in the first frame. Then it disappears.

You can see it in this links : http://www.1o1e.com/proje/lazzoni-mobilya-showroomlari?item=0#prettyPhoto[gallery1]/0/

How can I make it work properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check your initialisation of linkedin share button

Comment: thanks guys, i added this line and its work now :  changepicturecallback: function(){IN.init();},